# How to change the system fixed width font using terminal

Tags: fonts, preferences

Need way to change the system fixed width font USING TERMINAL! Because all ways do it using interface was useless for me. I haven't that inferface tabs was I found out in many sites.

System spec:

- OS Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS;
- desktop: GNOME 3.36.8;
- terminal: gnome-terminal 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

The configuration value of `org.gnome.desktop.interface.monospace-font-name` determines the system default fixed width font. You can change the configuration value to whatever font you like with `gsettings set` command from terminal.

For example, on my system the default monospace font is Ubuntu Mono 13. The following command changes that to Ubuntu Mono 11

> ```sh
> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Mono 11'
> ```

## Alternatives

Since the question suggests additional methods have been tried first but failed, it is worth mentioning alternative methods (using GUI):

### Dconf Editor tool

Kind of standard tool with the disadvantage that the font name must be typed (not selected from installed fonts). See also second option further down for a better alternative.

- install with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`,
- open it, go to `org.gnome.desktop.interface.monospace-font-name` key,
- turn off the 'Use default value' switch,
- now it is possible to type in the new Font name & size,
- press green Apply button at the bottom.

[image: Dconf editor 1]

[image: Dconf editor 2]

### Gnome-tweaks tool

This is another tool, probably not that mainstream, but works. Also has additional advantage that the font can be selected from the installed fonts (as opposed to typing the name, which is error prone).

- install with `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`,
- open the tool, go to the Fonts category,
- select the button next to "Monospace font",
- pick font from the list, pick the font size,
- press green Select button at the top.

[image: Gnome tweaks 1]

[image: Gnome tweaks 2]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, it may be worth mentioning that the font used in `gnome-terminal` also can be changed within `gnome-terminal`.

Preferences -> Unnamed[1] -> check "Custom Font" and pick the font family and font size to your liking.

[1] The name of the profile, which is "Unnamed" by default.